Using glmmPQL with known correlation matrix (GBLUP model)
I am working on a project attempting to apply a GBLUP (Genomic Best Linear Unbiased Prediction) model to genetic disease data. My goal is to model the probability of an individual developing a disease based on certain explanatory variables, including sex and random effects associated with Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms (SNPs).
My model formula is as follows:
library(MASS)
glmmPQL(Y ~ sex, 
        random = list(rs62 = ~1, rs63 = ~1),
        family = binomial, 
        data = data, 
        correlation = pdMat(matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1), nrow=2, byrow=FALSE)))

In this formula, $Y$ represents a binary response variable indicating whether an individual is affected by a disease. I am attempting to model this probability as a function of sex and random effects associated with two SNPs (rs62 and rs63).
I want to impose a variance structure $G$ on the random effects, where $G$ is the usual GBLUP matrix. Specifically, I would like the random effects $Zu$ to follow a gaussian distribution with variance $G$.
The following equation defines my model:
$$
\text{logit}(p) = X\beta + Zu + \epsilon,
$$
where $p$ is the probability of the individual developing the disease, $\beta$ is the vector of fixed coefficients associated with the explanatory variables (here, sex), $X$ is the design matrix for the fixed effects, $Z$ is the design matrix for the random effects, $u$ is the vector of random effects, and $\epsilon$ is the error term.
I am a bit lost on how to impose this variance structure $G$ in the glmmPQL formula. How can I specify this correctly in R?
Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!
